# Skip link not working in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, accessibility

trying to make a site WCAG 2.0 compliant by adding a "skip to content" link that is off-page but should then appear when a user tabs to it.

I'm new to tabindex so maybe I've go that wrong.
Here is the code in Wordpress:

```
    <body <?php body_class(); ?>> 
      <div class="top-bar" tabindex="0">
        <a href="#content" class="skip">Skip to content</a> 
      </div>    
    ...
```

And this is the css to make it work:

```
    /*skip link*/
    .skip {
      position: absolute;
      top: -1000px;
      left: -1000px;
      height: 1px;
      width: 1px;
      text-align: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .skip:focus {
       position: absolute;
       top: 50px;
       left: 50px;
       height: 50px;
       width: 100px;
       text-align: left;
       overflow: hidden;
    }
```

According my limited knowledge of the literature, screen readers and other assistive devices are supposed to be able to naturally tab to a link. The div the encloses it is not, but adding `tabindex="0"` is supposed to fix that.

If you could point me to what I'm doing wrong, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you tab to it? It doesn’t appear, or it appears but the link doesn’t work, or...?

Comment: i'm not sure if wordpress is getting in the way, but the method you're doing it is right.  having a CSS that moves the link into view when it receives focus.  you can see a working example at https://webaim.org/. perhaps look at their css/html to see how closely it matches what you're doing

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `tabindex` for that `top-bar` `div` container - the link will get focus in the tab sequence by itself. Just make sure the link (including its container) is before everything else, directly after the opening `body` tag.

Answer (score 0):

> According my limited knowledge of the literature, screen readers and other assistive devices are supposed to be able to naturally tab to a link. The div the encloses it is not, but adding tabindex="0" is supposed to fix that.

Not all assistive technologies can naturally focus on a link if it's not visible.

For instance, eye tracking devices or touchscreens will not benefit of the skip link.

Make the "skip to content" link visible, and remove the tabindex=0 which make it impossible to access the link.

Comment: can you explain *"remove the tabindex=0 which make it impossible to access the link."*  why does it make it impossible to access the link?  if the `<div>` has `tabindex=0` and the `<a>` is naturally focusable (if it has an `href`), then you'd just end up with two tab stops.  one on the `<div>` and one on the `<a>`.

Comment: Using eye tracking device for instance. But more generally, an anchor element should not contain another anchor element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a). By adding a `tabindex=0` on the `div`, the same should apply and user agents may consider the `div` as an anchor

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can meet the [bypass blocks criteria](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#bypass-blocks), one is to [add landmarks to your pages](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/page-structure/regions/). Skip links are also useful, especially for keyboard users who do not have a screenreader (e.g. for mobility issues).

In this case remove the tabindex from the parent div, and I think you need to include `.skip:active` as well.

Try the code snippets from this article on [hiding elements properly](https://www.nomensa.com/blog/2017/how-improve-web-accessibility-hiding-elements) using the clip method and showing on focus.

Comment: landmarks are awesome but i'm disappointed they're only useful with screen readers.  one day i hope browsers will surface this feature to keyboard users too